# Twig, how to add custom control next form widget

Tags: twig

i have an integer field containing bytes values, i want to display a custom select box (with choises 'MB', 'Gb', 'TB') next to form widget, so depending on selected choise convert the input value on bytes, (i.e. if input is 2 and selected choise is MB, convert the input as 2097152 bytes). How can i do that using twig? thanks...

Comment: Please provide a code example or pseudo-code of what you are trying to achieve or thinking about.

Comment: i want user enter values as MB, GB or TB, not as bytes, so i was thing in adding a select list next to input field and storage the value converted in bytes